# `poetry install`で`Max retries exceeded`エラーが発生したときの対応方法を教えてください。

Tags: python, poetry

## 環境

- python 3.7.1
- pip 20.1.1
- poetry 1.1.11

## やりたいこと

TravisCI上でpythonのテストやフォーマットチェックを実施しています。

```
dist: xenial
language: python
python:
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
  - "3.9"
install:
  - pip install poetry && poetry install
script:
   - make lint
   - make test
branches:
  only:
  - master
```

## 問題点

Python3.7では、たまに（10回に1回ぐらいの頻度？） `poetry install`が失敗します。

```
• Installing mypy-extensions (0.4.3): Installing...
• Installing mypy-extensions (0.4.3)
  • Updating numpy (1.16.4 -> 1.21.1): Pending...
• Updating numpy (1.16.4 -> 1.21.1): Failed
  SSLError
  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/numpy/1.21.1/json (Caused by SSLError(FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')))
```

https://app.travis-ci.com/github/kurusugawa-computer/annofab-cli/jobs/542618677

PyPIへのアクセス回数が多くて失敗しているようです。この場合、どのように対応するのがよいのでしょうか？

Comment: それだけ頻繁に PyPI にアクセスするのでしたら、ローカルストレージにキャッシュしておいてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど。その場合以下のサイトに従って、pipパッケージをキャッシュすればよいでしょうか？

Comment: `travis_retry` も使ってみます。install: travis_retry pip install myawesomepackage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のように`travis_retry`を指定したら、`poetry install`で失敗しなくなりました。

```
install:
  - pip install poetry
  - travis_retry poetry install
```

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#timeouts-installing-dependencies

> For commands which do not have a built-in retry feature, use the travis_retry function to retry it up to three times, if the return code is non-zero: